# compare values between comma in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table like:

```
businesses: 
id         name         tags
1          ken          my, oh, abc
2          jen          city, cle, dir
3          sen          state, NY, irs
...
```

I want to create query like:

select * from businesses where name like 'ken' and tags = 'oh'

How can i get value between first and second comma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    select * from businesses where
 name like 'ken' and FIND_IN_SET('oh',tags);
```

Comment: query above is not returning any results?

Comment: if 'oh' is present in tags column as a comma separated list than it will surely return results . Pl try to run with other data .

Comment: E.g in my db:                                                                 mysql> select LOCALITY_WITHIN_1KM from LOCALITY where ACTIVE_SYNC = 'Y' and  FIND_IN_SET(13682,LOCALITY_WITHIN_1KM);                     
+---------------------------------+
| LOCALITY_WITHIN_1KM             |
+---------------------------------+
| 1,14777,14778,13682,10234,10230 |
| 10230,13682,1,14777,14778       |
| 10234,1,14777,14778,13682       |
| 13682,1,14777,14778,10230,10234 |
| 1,14777,14778,13682,10234,10230 |
| 1,14777,14778,13682,10234,10230 |
+---------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.09 sec)

Comment: i think i got it problem is there is spaces between comma's. like: ca, oh, ta -> So i need to trim it some how